# Classification error "Layer error: Property 'class' of feature '00000000000000000000_0' is missing"

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, image-classification

I am trying perform a Random Forest classification using an uploaded shapefile of polygons with only one class = 0.  Get error `Cover crop classification: Layer error: Property 'class' of feature '00000000000000000000_0' is missing.`

Suspect not reading the "class" field (attribute) in the shapefile correctly, but the field prints.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ftracyd%2FDelawareChange%3ACoverCropClassification

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I can't read your code. Maybe you did not gave the permission. Try again!

However, I already tell you that this normally happens when you don't have the same string in the FeatureCollection properties.

Go to:
Geometry Imports > Edit Layer properties. Here you chose "FeatureCollection" and edit the properties (name it as "class" and the value as "0").

Other option:

```
var polygon = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(your_geometry_name, {'class': 0})]);
```

Use the variable "polygon" for futures classifications.

EDITED:

Add this lines:

```
polys = polys.map(function(ft){
return ee.Feature(ft).set('class', 0)
})
```

You will have another problem: the classifier will ask for another class to run the classification. I would do a class named "others". 
I'm not sure if there is another way but I think it should work.

EDITED 2:

First you need the create a geometry and collect samples to be training. I named it "Others". Transforme it in a FeatureCollection and edit the properties as I wrote above.

Then you need to add this new feature in the FeatureCollection(polys), adding this line:

```
polys = polys.merge(Other)
```

I'm not sure if you will have success only with 2 classes but try it.

Comment: Oops. My code and shapefile is now shared.  I did try going to Geometry imports, editing the layer and adding a property (class = 0).  I am unsure how to implement the other option with being newer to code editor.

Comment: Sorry, I still can´t read it: "Repository "users/tracyd/DelawareChange" does not exist."

Comment: My apologies. I must not understand how to share code.  I have "Anyone can read" checked under Share Repo: users/tracyd/DelwareChange.  My "CoverCropClassification" script is found t [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Ftracyd%2FDelawareChange%3ACoverCropClassification)

Comment: Nothing changed Tracy.
Try to go to "Get Link" and copy the URL.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/ff47e43e00c2d9fb3bb07eb72a2ce688

Comment: I edited my Answer Tracy. I hope it works!

Comment: Thank you.  I have created the Feature Collection and set the class equal to 0.  One last question, I hope, is how to make another class for the classifier?  All the training data is for one class.  Only trying to train on that class.

Comment: Tracy, I just edited the answer. If the console shows this error : "FeatureCollection (Error)Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements." Don't be panic it's because your are trying to print the variable training and the console can not support more then 500 elements.

Comment: No luck.  I added two additional classes.  Same error.  Even tried another classification routine.  Something is up with using a shapefile.

Comment: I can get this to work if you add points using the geometry to add points interactive. Change it to a Feature Collection and specify new class.  I think there is something I am doing incorrectly with the Feature Collection.